# "Enable API" button fails for Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I've been following the instructions on this page in order to enable the Cloud Pub/Sub API:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console

I have an account with a project where the free trial had previously expired. I successfully updated my billing information and re-enabled billing for the project. However, when I think click 'Enable API' for Cloud Pub/Sub, I repeatedly get the following error:

"Update failed with following error(s) for project settings: -- Failed to store the update"

This obviously isn't very helpful. Is there some minimum amount of time I need to wait after re-enabling billing, or is there some deeper issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue for the Google Maps Distance Matrix API after my free trial expired. I was eventually able to get it to work by: creating a new project, enabling the API in the new project (which processed without triggering the Error Message), and then returning to the old project and retrying the Enable API button. For whatever reason, it suddenly started working in the old project after I was able to enable it in the new one.